# Aggregate events with start and end times with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data for a number of events with start and end times like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2015-01-05', '2015-01-10', '2015-01-11'], 'end': ['2015-01-07', '2015-01-15', '2015-01-13'], 'value': [3, 4, 5]})
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
```

Out:

```
         end      start  value
0 2015-01-07 2015-01-05      3
1 2015-01-15 2015-01-10      4
2 2015-01-13 2015-01-11      5
```

Now I need to calculate the number of events active at the same time, and eg. the sum of their values. So the result should look something like this:

```
      date  count   sum
2015-01-05      1     3
2015-01-06      1     3
2015-01-07      1     3
2015-01-08      0     0
2015-01-09      0     0
2015-01-10      1     4
2015-01-11      2     9
2015-01-12      2     9
2015-01-13      2     9
2015-01-14      1     4
2015-01-15      1     4
```

Any ideas for how to do this? I was thinking about using a custom Grouper for groupby, but as far as I can see a Grouper can only assign a row to a single group so that doesn't look useful.

EDIT: After some testing I found this rather ugly way to get the desired result:

```
df['count'] = 1
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-05', '2015-01-15', freq='1D')

start = df[['start', 'value', 'count']].set_index('start').reindex(dates)
end = df[['end', 'value', 'count']].set_index('end').reindex(dates).shift(1)

rstart = pd.rolling_sum(start, len(start), min_periods=1)
rend = pd.rolling_sum(end, len(end), min_periods=1)

rstart.subtract(rend, fill_value=0).fillna(0)
```

However, this only works with sums, and I can't see an obvious way to make it work with other functions. For example, is there a way to get it to work with median instead of sum?

Comment: Reminiscent of counting winding, or opening-closing delimiters, but it's not obvious how to transplant the algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were using SQL, I would do this by joining an all-dates table to the events table, and then grouping by date. Pandas doesn't make this approach especially easy, since there's no way to left-join on a condition, but we can fake it using dummy columns and reindexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': ['2015-01-05', '2015-01-10', '2015-01-11'], 'end': ['2015-01-07', '2015-01-15', '2015-01-13'], 'value': [3, 4, 5]})
df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['dummy'] = 1
```

Then:

```
date_series = pd.date_range('2015-01-05', '2015-01-15', freq='1D')
date_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=date_series, dummy=1))

cross_join = date_df.merge(df, on='dummy')
cond_join = cross_join[(cross_join.start <= cross_join.date) & (cross_join.date <= cross_join.end)]
grp_join = cond_join.groupby(['date'])
final = (
    pd.DataFrame(dict(
        val_count=grp_join.size(),
        val_sum=grp_join.value.sum(),
        val_median=grp_join.value.median()
    ), index=date_series)
    .fillna(0)
    .reset_index()
)
```

The `fillna(0)` isn't perfect, since it makes nulls in the `val_median` column into 0s, when they should really remain nulls.

Alternatively, with [pandas-ply](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas-ply/) we can code that up as:

```
date_series = pd.date_range('2015-01-05', '2015-01-15', freq='1D')
date_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(date=date_series, dummy=1))

final = (
    date_df
    .merge(df, on='dummy')
    .ply_where(X.start <= X.date, X.date <= X.end)
    .groupby('date')
    .ply_select(val_count=X.size(), val_sum=X.value.sum(), median=X.value.median())
    .reindex(date_series)
    .ply_select('*', val_count=X.val_count.fillna(0), val_sum=X.val_sum.fillna(0))
    .reset_index()
)
```

which handles nulls a bit better.

Comment: Nice, thanks! That's a clever way of constructing the join table with the condition. I'll have to test it with some real data and see how the performance looks with larger tables.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with.  Got to think there's a better way

Given your frame

```
         end      start  value
0 2015-01-07 2015-01-05      3
1 2015-01-15 2015-01-10      4
2 2015-01-13 2015-01-11      5
```

and then

```
dList = []
vList = []
d = {}

def buildDict(row):   
    for x in pd.date_range(row["start"],row["end"]):  #build a range for each row
        dList.append(x)  #date list
        vList.append(row["value"]) #value list 

df.apply(buildDict,axis=1) #each row in df is passed to buildDict

#this d will be used to create our new frame
d["date"] = dList
d["value"] = vList

#from here you can use whatever agg functions you want
pd.DataFrame(d).groupby("date").agg(["count","sum"])
```

yields

```
            value
         count  sum
date        
2015-01-05   1   3
2015-01-06   1   3
2015-01-07   1   3
2015-01-10   1   4
2015-01-11   2   9
2015-01-12   2   9
2015-01-13   2   9
2015-01-14   1   4
2015-01-15   1   4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the cross join by exploding the dates, imputing the missing rows with `complete` from `pyjanitor`, before aggregating the dates:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df.assign(dates = [pd.date_range(start, end, freq='1D') 
                    for start, end 
                    in zip(df.start, df.end)])
   .explode('dates')
   .loc[:, ['value', 'dates']]
   .complete({'dates': lambda df: pd.date_range(df.min(), df.max(), freq='1D')})
   .groupby('dates')
   .agg(['size', 'sum'])
   .droplevel(level=0, axis='columns')
)

            size  sum
dates                
2015-01-05     1  3.0
2015-01-06     1  3.0
2015-01-07     1  3.0
2015-01-08     1  0.0
2015-01-09     1  0.0
2015-01-10     1  4.0
2015-01-11     2  9.0
2015-01-12     2  9.0
2015-01-13     2  9.0
2015-01-14     1  4.0
2015-01-15     1  4.0
```