# Adding a time interval and getting the counts of objects present at that time

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataset I have of a washing bay:

```
        Vehicle        Length     Arrival time         Departure time
1             Car        3    2020-01-03 10:30:00   2020-01-03 10:45:00
2             Car        3    2010-01-03 10:30:00   2020-01-03 11:15:00   
3             Bus        6    2020-01-03 10:45:00   2020-01-03 11:00:00   
4             Van        4    2020-01-03 11:00:00   2020-01-03 11:15:00   
5             Car        3    2020-01-03 11:15:00   2020-01-03 11:30:00
```

How do I get something like this?

```
           Time             Count    Length     
1   2020-01-03 10:15:00       0        0
2   2020-01-03 10:30:00       2        6
3   2020-01-03 10:45:00       2        9
4   2020-01-03 11:00:00       2        7
5   2020-01-03 11:15:00       1        3
6   2020-01-03 11:15:00       0        0
```

I am able to create the time column but having trouble creating the count and length columns where the count is the number of vehicles at the washing bay at that specific time (if the time is 10:30 and the vehicle leaves at 10:30 it is not counted), and the length is the total lengths of the vehicles in the washing bay at that time.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want to create the Time column? It is always every 15 minutes? When it will start?

Comment: groupby arrival time and sum the length

Comment: Yes using a time interval of 15 minutes, however if I use groupby, it would not capture if there were no vehicles arriving at that time. e.g. If the bus did not arrive at 10:45, then the Time column would not have a 10:45 row.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804508/3817720